# C# SkipWhile leaks memory if predicate is false

Tags: c#, linq, memory-leaks

```
// C:\logs\AzureSDK.log is ~2.5GB file
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\logs\AzureSDK.log").SkipWhile(line => false);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lines));
return;
```

This clearly **does not return an iterator and allocates memory internally until I get OOM**. Returning `true` in `SkipWhile` predicate does not lead to this and completes as expected (couple `MB` memory usage during the execution)

As per docs, method signature and common sense, `SkipWhile` must return an iterator and not load all the data into memory.

Machine info

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
Target 4.5.2, AnyCPU, Release
VS 2015 Update 3
NET 4.6.01586
```

Thoughts? I must be doing something stupid but unsure what

UPD: well the stupid thing was the string.Join I forgot about, which is appending to a single StringBuilder loading all the lines into memory.

I also checked SkipWhile sources and it's obviously perfectly fine:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipWhile<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    return SkipWhileIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipWhileIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    bool yielding = false;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (!yielding && !predicate(element)) yielding = true;
        if (yielding) yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SkipWhile` does return an enumerator. But then you use `string.Join` to concatenate everything, and therefore end up loading the whole file into memory

Comment: I knew I has to be something stupid, thanks

Comment: Not leakage, just usage ^_^

Comment: Question is a result of an obvious coding error and does not reflect original problem stated in title / body hence is confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SkipWhile` does return an enumerator. But then you use `string.Join` to concatenate everything, and therefore end up loading the whole file into memory.

If you change your code to process each line independently, you'll see that you use much less memory:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\logs\AzureSDK.log").SkipWhile(_ => false))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: I was so focused on minimizing the repro that I completely forgot about the join which obviously creates a StringBuilder and appends to it. Confirmed with memory profiler and looking at the string.Join source

Comment: trolling I suppose. Even though it's kind of obvious sometimes little things like this can hide in clear sight. Voted to close anyway since it's a programming error not the question it intended to be

Comment: Better deleting it then, no point in closing your own question

Comment: Questions with answers cannot be hence flagged for deletion.

Comment: @KooKiz Ya, it was strange when I saw my answer was upvoted and yours got downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is not on the SkipWhile, when you pass true in it is causing it to skip every line - returning no results for your join.

string.Join is causing the out of memory exception because it's trying to allocate a string that is 2.5gb in length.